# Python - Accessing instance attribute without `self.` inside __init__

Tags: python, oop, conventions, convention

My question is largely one of style or convention; however, it could have consequences which are not obvious to me that would effect which style is used.

If I have a class where instance attributes are defined by parameters to `__init__`, is it acceptable to access these parameters directly, rather than by the instance attribute? An example is given below:

```
from some_module import MyOtherClass

class MyClass(object)
    def __init__(self, uno, dos):
        self.uno = uno
        self.dos = dos

        """ This? """
        MyOtherClass(uno)
        MyOtherClass(dos)

        """ Or this? """
        MyOtherClass(self.uno)
        MyOtherClass(self.dos)
```

Comment: You have a callable module? (`MyOtherObject`)  Or it should be something like `from other_module import MyOtherClass`.

Comment: @wim The latter is correct; fixed.

Comment: To the duplicate: Thanks! I searched around a bit and couldn't find a similar question- I guess I couldn't find it because the title of that one is kind of incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes there is extra logic in each initialization:

```
def __init__(self, uno, dos=None):
    self.uno = list(uno)
    self.dos = dos or default_dos()
```

In that case, reusing the argument would result in an error.